# How to fix "Invalid IMEI " after Factory reset?

Tags: factory-reset

The question is simple "How to fix "Invalid IMEI " after Factory reset?"
After factory reset my phone starts showing "Invalid IMEI" on both SIM slots and I can't call or to being called.

The phone is [A738](http://www.chinabuye.com/a738-android-2-2-gps-tv-quad-band-dual-sim-smartphone-416mhz-2g-ram) with **Android 2.2.1** and **CPU chip** is Media Tek MTK6516 416MH

Hope that information is enough.

** UPDATE **

[This is the phone](http://www.chinabuye.com/a738-android-2-2-gps-tv-quad-band-dual-sim-smartphone-416mhz-2g-ram)

Comment: What phone?  Much more important than the CPU in my opinion.

Comment: The phone is A738 here is the link http://www.chinabuye.com/a738-android-2-2-gps-tv-quad-band-dual-sim-smartphone-416mhz-2g-ram

Comment: Have you installed CoPilot on this phone?

Comment: Yes, before the reset I have installed CoPilot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a good solution:

**DO IT AT YOUR OWN RISK**

1. Need to root the phone - I use z4root
2. Install Root.Explorer (in the archive)
3. Using Root Explorer you must replace (maybe you will need to press "Mount R/W" on top right corner of the program screen) **.modem.img**  from the archive to this location of the phone **/etc/firmware/.modem.img** (do not delete the old file !!! replace it!)
4. Set permissions for the **.modem.img** file to **rw-r--r--**
5. Restart the phone and maybe will be OK, but if it is not go to next step
6. IMEI information is stored in **/data/nvram/md/NVRAM/NVD_IMEI/MP0B_001**. Maybe changing of your original IMEI is not good idea because it is against the law but if you don't have copy of that file BEFORE the factory reset you can use temporary IMEI file located in the arhive.

[The archive with files needed](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=INKW3XLV)

Comment: the archive link is inactive please provide another. thanks

Comment: I re-upload it, must be ok now.

Comment: Since the archive was on MegaUpload it's gone now. Does anyone has a copy or can anyone upload it to some other file sharing service ?

Comment: comment by [Mircea D.](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/34527/mircea-d): *You can also create your own brand new IMEI file if you have the code at the back of your phone, with the IMEI generator. See [this guide](http://zwka.blogspot.ro/2013/01/invalid-imei-on-android-devices.html) for more details.* // @MirceaD You might wish to place that as an answer, including an excerpt of the linked guide.

Comment: I have formated the nvram accidentally with a tool. My IMEI also resets now. To keep my IMEI why do I need to replace the `modem.img` (4.89MB) and to what to replace? also is that is replaced, why need `/data/nvram/md/NVRAM/NVD_IMEI/` files? There I have `MP0B_001` 120 byte `ST6TA001` 412 byte `ST6TB001` 412 byte and not only MP0B_001. My chipset is MT6589T, phone THL: W8S

Answer (score 7):

1. Install the [Mobile MTK Engineering Mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.themonsterit.EngineerStarter&hl=en) app. This will only work on devices with a Mediatek chipset.

   > This Application allow you to run Advanced Setup from Engineering Mode Menu of MTK phones, also called SERVICE MODE

   Other apps which can show the MTK Engineering Mode Menu will probably work too.
2. If you can't find or don't know your phone's IMEI, then install the [Bb IMEI Generator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatcallie.bbimeigen&hl=en) app to generate one for you. If your phone has dual SIM support, you'll need two IMEIs. Note the generated IMEIs by Bb IMEI Generator.
3. In the Mobile MTK Engineering Mode app go to > MTK Settings > Connectivity > CDS Information > Radio Information > Phone 1.
4. At the AT+ line:

   [image]

   Enter `AT +EGMR=1,7,"ENTER-IMEI-HERE"`, then tap on 'Send AT Command'. If you have a dual SIM phone, enter `AT +EGMR=1,10,"ENTER-IMEI-HERE"` then tap on 'Send AT Command' again. Note: The quotes are included. There should be a space after `AT`.
5. You should get a notification that the AT Command(s) were successfully sent. Restart your device. You now shouldn't get the 'Invalid IMEI' notification.

Comment: This solution works even without getting notification. Note that copy-paste causes Mobile MTK Engineering Mode crash.

Answer (score 3):

Before proceeding, check your country's law regarding tampering IMEI. It might be illegal. However, the answer is meant to restore the IMEI back to original.
The answer can work on Mediatek devices mt65{89,75,77,92,82}. Simply, its applicable on many Mediatek devices.

In my situation, `T1000's` answer didn't work for my device [Micromax A110q Canvas 2 Plus](http://www.gsmarena.com/micromax_a110q_canvas_2_plus-5482.php). I used this  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yfn72r9ybyo) ([backup](http://www.4shared.com/video/6iru6w-Bce/CUBOT_or_MTK_Phone_IMEI_NVRAM_.html)) on YouTube which first format and then flashes your device.

> If you have a an MTK-Phone that has an invalid IMEI after performing a factory reset from nandroid, your NV-RAM is corrupted and you CAN NOT fix this with any of the MANY IMEI repair tools on the web. YOU NEED TO FORMAT YOUR NV-RAM and flash a stock image! DON'T WASTE YOUR TIME WITH IMEI TOOLS!
>
> After that you can just restore your original NANDROID backup and be on your way again! ([Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yfn72r9ybyo))

**Remember to take a backup of everything you think is important for you.**

---

#### Method #1

**Procedure**:

> 1. Download a scatter-based ROM (Stock ROM preferred) for your device. Google for such with details like device model name, chipset, etc. You can also look at this [collection](http://androidxda.com/category/download) listed at Androidxda.
> 2. Download ADB drivers for your device, install them and verify that your device is getting detected. You can Google for them like Step 1.
> 3. Extract files from downloaded ROM and look for Scatter File.
> 4. Download latest [SP-Flash Tool](http://androidxda.com/smart-phone-flash-tool) and follow the usage guide either from the aforementioned [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yfn72r9ybyo) (using old version of the tool) or from [here](http://androidxda.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool).
> 5. Extract this tool, look for **Flash_tool.exe** and execute it by `Right-click -> Run as Administrator`.
> 6. Once the interface comes up, click `Scatter-Loading` button and locate the Scatter file there.
> 7. If you have custom recovery installed and don't want to replace it, then uncheck it and check the rest of the listed options (partitions). It is better to uncheck the recovery in case, the tool doesn't succeed.
> 8. Click the `Format` option. Under `Auto Format Flash` check `Format whole flash except bootloader` and uncheck rest ([0:57/1:57](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yfn72r9ybyo)). Make sure `Validation` is checked.
> 9. Hit `Format/OK` and then connect your phone through USB cable into PC, remove and plug the battery but don't turn it on manually. You may have to press `Vol. Up` or `Vol. Down` button to let the PC detect your phone.
> 10. The tool will format the partitions and will show a green ring as success.
> 11. Press the `Download` button and re-insert the battery again.
> 12. A green ring will be shown if its flashed well.
> 13. Close the tool, unplug the phone, start and boot into the Android. Check the IMEI now.
>
> (Source YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yfn72r9ybyo) and Androidxda [guide](http://androidxda.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool).)

---

#### Method #2

It could be possible that you might not be able to see IMEI still, but we've come far away from Invalid IMEI issue. If the issue persist, a different issue with IMEI I assume, then consider the solution on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CokpIVGPBw) ([backup](http://www.4shared.com/video/oH6si1D_ba/Android_phone_invalid_imei_rep.html)). You can also look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lS4wThAdPmQ) ([backup](http://www.4shared.com/video/ClFs4UDBce/Android_phone_imei_change_by_A.html)) solution which is published by the same uploader.

This solution requires [Maui Meta 3G](http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f457/update-maui-meta-3g-ver-6-1316-1-a-1692422/), [Scatter based Stock ROM](http://androidxda.com/category/download), [CDC Drivers](http://www.androiddevs.net/2014/11/21/permanent-imei-restore-tool-mediatek-phones/). Google them to download the latest version. You may look the [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CokpIVGPBw) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lS4wThAdPmQ) video, or this [guide](http://www.androiddevs.net/2014/11/21/permanent-imei-restore-tool-mediatek-phones/) for the procedure. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a synopsis for Maui Meta 3G.

**Procedure**:

> 1. First enable USB Debugging in your phone. To do this go to `Settings -> Developer` options and enable USB Debugging in it. In case you don’t find developer options in your settings just go to `Settings -> About phone`. There you can see build number. Tap it 7-8 times and you can get Developer options now.
> 2. Now install Maui META 3G tool then open it after installation.
> 3. Click `Options -> Connect` smart phone into META mode.
> 4. Then click `Reconnect`.
> 5. Now turn off the device and connect it to pc using USB data cable.
> 6. The device will boot up and stay in boot logo (META mode) and won’t go past it (don’t panic it is normal).
> 7. As soon as PC detects the mobile it will start searching for drivers.
> 8. If it fails to install any driver, mainly CDC driver you have to manually install it (this driver is mandatory and without it Maui tool will not detect your device). Hop down to the next point to know how to install CDC drivers. For Windows 7 and above make sure you have disabled **Digital signature Verification**.  You can Google out [how to disable digital signature verification](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+disable+digital&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=lDVuVOeEG-LV8gerj4HwAQ#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&q=how+to+disable+digital+signature+in+windows+).
> 9. Go to `Control panel -> Device manager`, locate CDC… (The CDC… option will be displayed until the device is connected in META mode, it will disappear after you disconnect it). Locate CDC in device manger list and right click on it. Now choose `update driver software -> Browse my computer driver software -> then browse Android_Gadget_CDC_driver.inf through browse option -> Click next to install driver -> Choose install it anyway -> done`.
> 10. After successfully installing the drivers  the Maui tool will detect your device.
> 11. Close the pop-up info window then choose IMEI download from the drop down menu right below the menu bar of the Maui Tool.
> 12. [Main app](http://www.androiddevs.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Main-app.png).
> 13. After clicking IMEI download it will popup a window like below.
> 14. [vlcsnap-2014-11-21-00h20m20s28](http://www.androiddevs.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/vlcsnap-2014-11-21-00h20m20s28.jpg).
> 15. Click Change NVRAM database file and load your device stock ROM database file. (This file will be available in your device SP Tool flashable stock ROM. Don’t use any other device database file and use only your device file).
> 16. After loading NVRAM database file successfully now enter your IMEI(SIM_1) and hit `Download` to flash.  Repeat the same process for SIM_2.
> 17. Now you have flashed the IMEI successfully on your phone and you can close the tool.
> 18. Unplug the device from PC, remove the battery and insert it back again.
> 19. Now turn on the device and DONE…!! Now you will have your lost IMEI back permanently.
>       [More Info : [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cftsawym7yI&feature=youtu.be) ([backup](http://www.4shared.com/video/X3pyzhVJba/Permanent_IMEI_FIx_For_Mediate.html)) on YouTube]
>
> ([Source](http://www.androiddevs.net/2014/11/21/permanent-imei-restore-tool-mediatek-phones/))

---

#### About SP Flash Tool

> Smart Phone Flash Tool (SP Flash Tool) allows you to Flash any Stock Rom or any Custom on the Android Smartphone.

---

**Note**: I've provided backup for every YouTube video if the original cannot be reached somehow. 
Method 1 is tested by me. Method 2 is tested from the video only. Procedure for Method #2 is mentioned for the purpose of quoting and answering.