# How can I restore IMEI code after factory reset?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, factory-reset, htc-hero, imei

The phone is a Hero H2000 dual sim with Android v2.2.1, MTK Platform

I get an Invalid IMEI error after a factory reset.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities. The first starts with checking the "Related" section to the right of this page, which gives you some good candidates which already contain answers/solutions, e.g.:

- [How to fix “Invalid IMEI ” after Factory reset?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8570/how-to-fix-invalid-imei-after-factory-reset?rq=1)

Next, there are some video tutorials on Youtube on this topic, e.g.:

- [How to Change or Repair Your IMEI Number On Android Cell Phone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6s40aLz5-QQ&feature=related)
- [HOW TO SOLVED Invalid IMEI](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQnB1fMJy7U&feature=related)

My short [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+%22Invalid+IMEI%22+error) also found some forum threads providing hints and solutions, e.g.:

- [Invalid IMEI after Reset to Factory Defaults](http://club.dx.com/forums/forums.dx/threadid.1004466)

I couldn't verify any of the mentioned solutions myself (luckily, I've never been affected by this problem) -- but I hope at least one of them will prove helpful to you.

Comment: I lost my IMEI today. Searched Google and android.stackexchange.com for solutions, but could not find any. I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 I9505. Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: @SuperThomasLab I have no Samsung device, so I'm the wrong person to guide you step-by-step. I only know with Sammies it has to do with the `/efs` partition usually.

Comment: I already restored the `/efs` partition, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: No more ideas then from my end. Maybe you open a new question (include a reference to this one to avoid someone counting it as "duplicate") with details what you've already tried, to attract those who might be able to assist?

Comment: I posted a question here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113667/how-to-restore-the-imei-number-on-the-samsung-galaxy-s4-i9505