# Have I completely lost my IMEI?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, imei

I'm stuck with the generic IMEI (004999010640000). I've tried a number of the various workarounds (GSII_Repair, manually deleting the /efs folder, flashing stock and trying both of those from stock, re-flashing CM10 and trying from CM10 again...) with no luck. I was actually missing files in my /efs folder before flashing stock, but even with the full /efs folder I can't find my actual IMEI. So am I screwed?

Comment: Have you tried all the suggestions from [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19094/how-can-i-restore-imei-code-after-factory-reset)?

Comment: All but the video showing to echo AT+EGMR=<imeistuffhere>, but I can't find anything about that for US phones (the video and everything else I see is referring to multi-IMEI devices, and there are two parameters that I'd like to know the meaning of before I try this on my phone).

Comment: Also, it appears that the /dev/pttycmd1 device doesn't exist on the i777.

Comment: How did you flash stock?  Did you do it through Odin with re-partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handset is not damaged, not totally.

But you do need to get some professional help, someone who is willing to carry out the procedure in restoring it, *provided* that someone has the necessary tools at their disposal.

However, you can fix your IMEI using a highly specialized but expensive *repair box* such as [Z3X](http://z3x-team.com/), [NSPro](http://www.fonefunshop.co.uk/Unlocking/nsdongle.htm), to name but a few.

Mostly, smartphone users do not have access to them and only repair labs or specialists have them.

Comment: This is what I suspected after quite a bit of searching. I've since decided to just live with it, as it's mostly not a problem. The main time it causes trouble is if someone reports a phone using it as stolen, which has happened to me twice since I first lost the IMEI, but not recently. It's also troublesome for apps that use it as an identifier, but in one case it's worked to my advantage.