# How to restore the IMEI number on the Samsung Galaxy S4 I9505? (IMEI=Unknown, Baseband=Unknown, Sim Card Not Detected)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, device-firmware, partitions, imei

## Information:

Hello, I lost my **IMEI** number on my `Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9505` today and I would like to restore my original **IMEI** back to my phone. I still have my original **IMEI** of my phone written down. And my Sim Card is not detected.

**I do not have any backups!**
I didn't make any backups of `/efs` (sorry!), will do that when I have this problem fixed and backup it on all my computers.

I have searched **Google** and **www.Android.StackExchange.com** but couldn't find anything that worked for me. (**So please don't mark this as a duplicate question**)

---

## In short:

- Samsung Galaxy S4 **GT-I9505**
- I live in **The Netherlands**
- My carrier is **KPN** (if you wanted to know that)
- I have my **IMEI** number written down
- **I do not have any backups of `/efs`!** (sorry!)
- IMEI = Unknown
- Baseband = Unknown
- Sim Card not detected

---

## Screenshots:

I dialed `*#06#` to get the **IMEI** number:

[image: Screenshot - I dialed <code>*#06#</code> to get the **IMEI** number]

The hidden menu in Android: (`*#*#4636#*#*` or `*#*#INFO#*#*`):

[image: Screenshot - The hidden menu in Android: (*#*#4636#*#* or *#*#INFO#*#*)]

---

## What I have tried:

- Of course, I flashed the stock ROM back on my phone. (Android 4.4.2)
- I downloaded a backup of `/efs` from someone else on the internet and flashed that on my phone. However the `IMEI` is still "Unknown".
- When I flash the stock ROM on my phone for my country (The Netherlands), **it did restore my IMEI**. However WIFI didn't work on the stock ROM, and when I flash **Cyanogenmod** back on my phone, I don't have an **IMEI** anymore. (So I think the **IMEI** wasn't written permanently on my phone).

---

**Any help is appreciated.**
If I need to add some more information, just tell me. **Thanks!**

Comment: If you are able to restore your IMEI by flashing a stock ROM, try to find an appropriate MODEM and flash it *after* CM. it seems like CM does not come with a compatible MODEM for your device so give it a try.

Comment: @GiantTree I will give it a try, thanks for your response.

Comment: @GiantTree I flashed the **appropriate modem** for my country. However, my **IMEI** is still **"Unknown"** like before and my **SIM Card** is still **not detected**. Do you have any other solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of CM are you using? AntaresOne & Alucard24's optimized CM12? Seems like you are using a ROM that is not in a stable state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all this was a simple bug in the `cm12.1-20150623` nightly. It has been fixed in the `cm12.1-20150629` nightly. For more information about this bug you look here: [CM12.1 Nightly no Sim found](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/111447-cm121-nightly-sim-no-found/page__st__20#entry525268). For all the people helped me so far, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access.

Try apps like [XPOSED Imei Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vivek.imeichanger)

- Just open app and select *Set Orignal* if it doesnt show your orignal imei just type the imei you have written and tap apply.

Comment: This won't be a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you flashed a custom ROM using TWRP or CWM Recovery and your IMEI no longer be able to show or unknown baseband:

1. First, root your device.
2. Dial *#1234# to find the CSC Version (example: Ã750FODM1ARK9), then copy it. Change the first letter with
3. Use a file manager, go to EFS Folder, edit `nv_data.bin` and replace the 6th line with the CSC Code, and save it.

   [image]
4. Reboot your device, your EFS will restore and IMEI is done.

Comment: Looks like there's missing info on "change the first letter with... [what character?]"

Answer (score 0):

find the correct baseband first(baseband depends for which country the phone was made). if your baseband is still unknown try to write nv for the phone so that at the correct cp file (modem) you will find ime = 000000... or 35000.... or any other number different from unknown or null imei. when you get this write imei certificate file. finished phone fixed.
**remember** use only stock os and root the phone.