# Invalid IMEI on motorola A853 milestone

Tags: motorola-milestone, imei

I was changing the OS of my Motorola A853 milestone, and the IMEI turned invalid; it just shows "00000000".

I found this answer here about something similar 
[How to fix "Invalid IMEI " after Factory reset?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8570/how-to-fix-invalid-imei-after-factory-reset) but the link with the files is invalid.

Comment: That's a different phone so it won't work.  However a similar process might work if you find the correct modem for your device -- have you looked on XDA?