# how you can lose / keep IMEI over after factory reset?

Tags: factory-reset, restore, imei

[Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8570/how-to-fix-invalid-imei-after-factory-reset) it says as a solution for a type of a phone. There are other question ( upvoted) but closed by somebody marked as to localized. Of course it is localisez for each type... why don't want to allow to get help?

I am searching like a week how to solve my THL W8S problem. 
I could go on others answers too, but those questions it seems they aren't active anymore.

Tried with MTK tools, and other tools, since this phone has a MK5689T version on it. Used the hidden engineering mode too with dialing a "secret" number. On that case I could set the old IMEI back, but that will be lost after factory reset.

Please correct me if  I am wrong:

```
/data/nvram/md/NVRAM/NVD_IMEI/MP0B_001
```

This holds the IMEIs (  I have dual sim )

`/data` is wiped after Factory Reset => IMEI lost after factory reset.

Question is what to do to make it persistent?

At `/etc/firmware/modem.img` I have the .img, but don't know how to read it, where to mount it,even on Linux after saving to desktop.
Has that img inside of him a MP0B_001 file? Would it work if I mount , unpack change the file and repack?

I have downloaded the official rom: http://www.thlmobilestore.com/news/

THL W8S ROM support: Multilang

Friday, September 27, 2013 2:34:40 AM America/Los_Angeles

Title: ThL W8S

ROM Version: ROM Android 4.2.1

Link: Here

The ThL_W8s.JB2.FHD.EN.COM.16P256_MT6589TV1.0.3_20130815 content is:

[image]

If I unpack  I see a boot.img 
That file need to unpacked to get the modem.img?

Where it stored the phone serial number? - I  need to restore that too ( to original one)  I have found only which environment properties has it, not where it is stored. It is formatted the NVram accidentally by pressing the Format on a SP Flash Tool.

At baseband version I see: Moly.wr8.w1248.md.wg.mp.v7 and I see a file BPLGUInfoCustomAppSrcP_MT6589_S00_MOLY_WR8_W1248_MD_WG_MP_V7 there it should be written the SN + IMEI?

Thanks for any try to help.