# How can I root the Micromax A110Q

Tags: rooting

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS and want to root my micromax A110Q.

Answer (score 0):

**Note #1**:

- Rooting Mediatek devices isn't usually a clean area. Please remember that this solution is to help you out only and is not a mandate, which means the responsibility of recovering device (if required) lies upon the reader only.
- Taking backup is very important. Consider the answers [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) to take backup. I can't stress this more. Please do not ignore this step.

**Note #2**: Keep you device's battery charged, possibly above 80%. Best is to keep it fully charged. Few folks sometimes report that low-battery during flashing resulted in [soft/hard-bricking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29741/what-does-it-mean-to-brick-your-phone) of their device.

---

I'm aware of two methods to root this device and both are tested by me on this very device.

#### Method #1

This method will [sideload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideloading) an app in your Android. You can see this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22884/how-does-rooting-work) to know how this kind of apps works. Also, I'm using this [guide](http://androidxda.com/root-micromax-a110q-canvas-2-plus) on [AndroidXDA](http://androidxda.com/) to corroborate my answer.

**Instructions**:

1. Go to **Settings → Security** and check **Unknown sources** -- in order to sideload apps.
2. Download and install Framaroot from any of the following links:

   - [Framaroot's website](http://framaroot.net/index.html)
   - [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276)
   - [AndroidXDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2784451&d=1402084843)
3. Launch the app and **Install SuperSU** will be shown selected. If not, do choose it.
4. Tap any of the following options(exploits):

   - Boromir
   - Faramir
   - Barahir

   and wait for few seconds.
5. If the exploit you chose works fine then you would see the following or similar message:

   > ```
   > Success :-)... Superuser and su binary installed. You have to reboot your device.
   > ```
   >
   > ---
   >
   > ```
   >                                     OK
   > ```

   Otherwise, choose the rest of the two options. But eventually, it would work. (Worked on my A110Q).
6. Reboot your device and you would see a new app installed in your device named [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu).
7. You can use any of the root checker apps [here](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=check+root&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiDAoKY2hlY2sgcm9vdHoCGACKAQIIAQ%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljLloJ8) on Play Store to see whether [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) is intercepting root access, or apps can detect `su` binary.

**Congrats!** Your device is now rooted.

---

#### Method #2

This method is a typical technique of flashing Recovery partition with a custom recovery and then flashing SuperSu zip file from the latter accompanied by installing an app from Play Store.

**Note #3**: The following instructions are platform dependent, tested and mostly works on Microsoft Windows 7 OS.

This method uses a tool named [SP Flash Tool](http://androidxda.com/smart-phone-flash-tool) to flash Recovery partition of your device using a scatter(text) file. I've covered this tool in **Method #1** of an answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8570/how-to-fix-invalid-imei-after-factory-reset/105966#105966) with links to some videos(to familiarize yourself). You can also see this [guide](http://www.theandroidhow.com/2014/06/how-to-flash-stock-custom-recovery-sp-flash-tool.html) as well.

About Scatter file : *Scatter file has the index of location of partitions (including boundaries) your device has*.

**Instructions:**

1. Download ADB drivers for your device, install them and verify that your device is getting detected. You can either query Google for them or download them from [here](http://androidxda.com/download-micromax-usb-drivers).
2. Download a scatter-based ROM (Stock ROM preferred) for your device. Query Google for such with details like `device model name`, `chipset`, etc. You can download it from [here](http://androidxda.com/download-micromax-stock-rom-models) as well. Note that the solution needs only a text file which is packed inside the ROM.

   As an alternative of downloading this ROM, you can generate your own Scatter Based file. The instructions are mentioned [here](http://www.theandroidhow.com/2014/05/easy-steps-to-make-android-scatter-file.html). I didn't try the instructions there so I can't cover them here. On a side note, I recommend downloading stock ROM since its always good to have this ROM ready for flashing in emergency.
3. Extract files from downloaded ROM and look for `.txt` file with name similar to `MT6589_Android_scatter.txt`. Note down the location of this file.
4. - Download latest [SP-Flash Tool](http://androidxda.com/smart-phone-flash-tool).
   - Download a custom Recovery for your device. Alike step 1 querying Google is the option here. Mostly, the recovery you might get is either [CWM or Philz Touch recovery](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/All_About_Recovery_Images). You can consider these links to download [CWM recovery](http://forum.droidarena.in/Thread-Micromax-A110Q-Canvas-2-Plus-CWM-Recovery) or [Philz Touch Recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/micromax-canvas-2/development/cwm-philz-touch-recovery-t2364465).
   - Download **SuperSU** zip from [here](http://download.chainfire.eu/396/SuperSU/). The name might be similar to `UPDATE-SuperSU-vX.YZ.zip`. Put this `.zip` file into the root directory (Home folder) of your Internal SD card. You can do so by firing up your favorite File Manager.
5. Connect your phone via USB cable into PC.
6. Extract [SP Flash Tool](http://androidxda.com/smart-phone-flash-tool), look for **Flash_tool.exe** and execute it by doing  **Right-click → Run as Administrator**.
7. Once the interface comes up, click **Scatter-Loading** button, locate the scatter file (from Step 3) there and proceed with it -- this will list some partition names (unfamiliar names possibly) like `MBR`, `UBOOT`, `BOOTIMG`, etc.
8. Make sure that all the entries below **name** are unchecked except **Recovery** -- we do not want to replace the content of any existing partition other than of Recovery.
9. Click on **Recovery**, locate the Recovery file you downloaded in step 4 and proceed with it. Below the **location** you would see the file path of your Recovery file (like `C:\Users\...`).
10. **Power off** your phone (do not disconnect) and click the **Download** button in the tool.
11. If the flashing proceeds successfully you would see a small window with green circle. Otherwise, you would have to query Google for any troubleshooting. You can now unplug your phone and power on.
12. Power off your phone completely (it will vibrate after screen goes blank during this process). Press and hold "Volume Up" + "Volume Down" + "Power" button simultaneously. You'll see two options:

    - Recovery Mode: Volume Up
    - Factory Mode: Volume Down

    Press "Volume Up" button then select the entry **[Recovery Mode]** using "Volume Up" button and press "Volume Down" button to proceed.
13. You'll now boot into your custom Recovery (CWM for me).
14. - For CWM go to **Install zip → choose zip from /sdcard/sdcard0** and use "Volume Up/Down" buttons to go up and down in the entries. Select your `.zip` file (from step 4) entry and press "Power" button to install. Choose **Yes** to install SuperSU zip -- this step will copy `su` binary *et al.* in your system which will be used by a Play Store app.
    - For Philz, look for similar options since most of the popular recoveries have similar options to flash a `.zip`.
15. If step 14 proceeds successfully, reboot your device and download [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) from Play Store.
16. Launch the app. Choose **Continue** and it will ask two options, choose **TWRP/CWM**. It might reboot your device but will eventually get installed.
17. For verification see whether [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) has been successfully installed and working, or not, by using any app that requests Root privileges. E.g. See these [apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=check+root&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiDAoKY2hlY2sgcm9vdHoCGACKAQIIAQ%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljLloJ8).

**Congrats!** Your device is now rooted.

---

#### About Framaroot

> Now you can root your android device without PC, just use framaroot. This app including several exploits named as the heroes of the book "The Lord of the Rings" Gandalf, Boromir, Pippin, Legolas, Sam, Frodo, Aragorn and Gimli. You can install Superuser and su binary on phone or tablet from android version 2.x to 4.x.

#### About SP Flash Tool

> Smart Phone Flash Tool (SP Flash Tool) allows you to Flash any Stock Rom or any Custom on the Android Smartphone.

---

<sub>Note: I'm aware of [MTK Droid Tools](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2160490) as well. Aforementioned methods should possibly work out easily for you. In case they don't or you wanna explicitly use this app for rooting (it has some other [useful features](http://www.chinaphonearena.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=2531) as well), then consider this [XDA link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=38337401&postcount=5).</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Download ADB drivers for your device, install them and verify that your device is getting detected. You can either query Google for them or download them from here.
Download a scatter-based ROM (Stock ROM preferred) for your device. Query Google for such with details like device model name, chipset, etc. You can download it from here as well. Note that the solution needs only a text file which is packed inside the ROM.

As an alternative of downloading this ROM, you can generate your own Scatter Based file. The instructions are mentioned here. I didn't try the instructions there so I can't cover them here. On a side note, I recommend downloading stock ROM since its always good to have this ROM ready for flashing in an emergency.

every thing good but where i can download

This website also provides [Micromax a106 flash file](http://atozfiles.com/android-firmware-files/download-micromax-a106-flash-file/) but not working.