# Rooting the Micromax Canvas Spark

Tags: rooting

How can I root a Micromax Canvas Spark?

I have found many procedures on the Internet, but I am not sure whether they will work or not.

Comment: Which methods did you find? Have you tried any of them? Have you looked at the "generic" methods listed in [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/981)

Comment: If you are afraid of trying long root proceduers.
Try Root Apps because generally micromax devices are Mediatek and can be rooted with apps like Root Master, iRoot etc.

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with [this method](http://versatileposts.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-to-root-micromax-canvas-spark.html) involving some `super-root.apk` then use [SP Flash Tool](http://androidxda.com/smart-phone-flash-tool) to [flash recovery](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/109337/96277) with a custom one. I see that this is a new device and custom recoveries aren't available yet. However, there is a guide [here](http://www.theandroidhow.com/2014/05/how-to-make-flash-cwm-recovery-without.html) which claims to make CWM recovery for your device in few simple steps. Check it out.