# SIM card not detecting and imei null after flashing recovery (intex aqua i5-not i5 HD)

Tags: recovery-mode, connection-issues, sim-card

I wanted to flash custom ROM .

- Before that I flashed a custom recovery img.
- Then I tried flashing custom ROM zip file using **flashify**. It said

> flashing completed and reboot to continue.
>
> When rebooted, it didn't enter Recovery mode. So I installed CWM recovery for my model and tried entering recovery. It still did not enter into Recovery mode.
>
> Now I flashed TWRP recovery IMG and tried entering Recovery mode. A black empty box showed up instead of Recovery menu.
>
> Then I booted phone normally and there was no Sim card detection.
>
> I tried restoring recovery but sim card detection problem still persist.
>
> My android is rooted . I can enter into Safe mode easily but not able to enter Recovery mode nor able to Factory Reset my phone. Except Sim detection problem everything works fine. WiFi apps, movies everything. I need help.

Comment: You can try Method #1 or Method #2  here in this answer. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8570/how-to-fix-invalid-imei-after-factory-reset/105966#105966

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ...the custom rom you have flashed doesnt had Modem binaries of your phone...
 A rom consist of many parts that operates the device the Modem binaries are responsible to operate network related operations...

You can download stock rom of your device then extract modem binary from it convert it to flashable file than flash only the modem binary in your device if that works than ok.

Else flash with your stock rom...the problem is not in ypur device ...the problem is in that custom rom binaries..

Good day..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it this way:

1. Format your Android using SP Flash Tool
2. Flash  stock ROM
3. Download Maui Meta 3G version 6.1308.0, and connect your device via Meta mode (no need to root)
4. Select Update Parameter option →  check all boxes → save it

Done!

Comment: Could you link the tools you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

IMEI Problem? Here's the solution (For MediaTek phones only):

1. Type on Dialer `*#*#3646633#*#*` → Connectivity → Radio Info → phone 1
2. Type to the textbox 'AT+EGMR=1,7,"(Your IMEI)" (Example: `AT+EGMR=1,7,"0123456789101112"`)
3. At your SIM select 'Phone 2' → change 1,7 into 1,10 (Example: `AT+EGMR=1,10,"0123456789101112"`)

On other phone download [Chamelephon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cryptotel.chamelephon) app, then put your IMEI, then reboot (need root).