# Installing CyanogenMod 12 on Motorola Moto G2 (XT1068)

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-moto-g2

I want install CyanogenMod 12 on my Motorola Moto G 2nd Gen (XT1068) with Lollipop 5.0.2. Please help me on the procedure.

I've tried apps like towelroot, Kingo, etc. but they don't support Lollipop.

Comment: You don't need to root into install a custom ROM.

Answer (score 4):

Follow guide below:
**This will void your warranty and wipe your device so make a backup.
CyanogenMod 12 is still a nightly so there are bugs.**
**Make sure your computer has working fastboot and adb.**

Follow these steps:

**Step 1: Unlock Bootloader**

1. Enable USB debugging on the device.
2. Connect the device to the computer through USB.
3. From a terminal on a computer, type: `adb reboot bootloader`
4. Once device booted to fastboot mode, type: `fastboot devices`
5. If you don't see your device serial number then fastboot is not working correctly.
6. If you see `no permissions fastboot`, try running fastboot as root.
7. Now type: `fastboot oem get_unlock_data`
8. Visit the Motorola Bootloader Unlock website and follow the instructions there to obtain your unlock key.
9. If the device doesn't automatically reboot, reboot it from the menu. It should now be unlocked.
10. Since the device resets completely, you will need to **re-enable USB debugging on the device** to continue.

**Step 2: Installing recovery using fastboot**

1. Download TWRP recovery img for your device.
2. Connect the Moto G 2014 to the computer via USB.
3. Open a terminal on your PC and type: `adb reboot bootloader`
4. Once device is in fastboot mode, type `fastboot devices`
5. If you don't see your device serial number then fastboot is not working correctly.
6. If you see `no permissions fastboot`, try running fastboot as root.
7. Install recovery by typing: `fastboot flash recovery your_recovery_image.img`
8. Once completed: Boot to recovery: Hold Volume Down & Power simultaneously. On the next screen use Volume Down to scroll to recovery and then use Volume Up to select.

> **Note:** Some ROMs overwrite recovery at boot time so if you do not plan to immediately boot into recovery to install CyanogenMod, please be aware that this may overwrite your custom recovery with the stock one.

**Step 3: Installing CyanogenMod from recovery**

1. Download the CyanogenMod package for your device that you'd like to install to your computer.
   **Optional**: Download 3rd party applications packages, like Google Apps which are necessary to download apps from Google Play.
2. Boot to recovery mode, and connect the phone to your computer through USB.
3. Hold Volume Down & Power simultaneously. On the next screen use Volume Down to scroll to recovery and then use Volume Up to select
4. In ClockworkMod Recovery, use the physical volume buttons to move up and down.
5. Optional (Recommended): Select backup and restore to create a backup of your current ROM.
6. Select wipe data/factory reset.
7. Then go to `install zip -> install zip from sideload`. Now on your PC in the terminal type `adb sideload update.zip` (Replace `update.zip` with your cyanogenmod zip)
8. **Optional** Install Gapps: go to `install zip -> install zip from sideload`. Now on your PC in the terminal type `adb sideload gapps.zip` (Replace `gapps.zip` with your gapps zip)
9. Once installation has finished, return to the main menu and select reboot system now. The device will now boot into CyanogenMod.

> **Note:** If you want root access you need to enable it in developer options.

More information: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_titan

Hope my answer helped. (I typed it on my android phone running CyanogenMod 12)

Comment: +1. Thank goodness you corrected it. It is readable and useful now. :) However, as I asked @Izzy I'll ask you too: Wouldn't I have to wipe `system` as well in Step 3.6, or does the ROM has some instructions to wipe the `system` but not `data` and `cache`?

Comment: The `ROM.zip` does automatically wipe `/system`. That's why you FIRST need to install the `ROM` and then the `GAPPS`.

Comment: @Firelord if you're going to install a new ROM anyway, wiping `/system` cannot hurt, can it? :) They have that in several instructions. Whether it's really needed is something else :)

Comment: @Izzy It actually hurted my device pretty well :) An year ago I wanted to install Cyanogenmod on my device and was instructed to wipe `/system` through recovery along with data reset. I did so but the ROM had signature issue so I dropped the idea. I restored my stock ROM backup, and to my surprise my IMEI and Baseband were missing. Nothing helped except the lengthy remedy I wrote in this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/105966/96277) few weeks ago. That's why I asked this silly point to both poster and you.

Comment: Ugh! That's harsh. IMEI shouldn't be in `/system` AFAIK; as that's device-specific, it makes absolutely no sense. Sounds like a Samsung-special (but they use `/efs` for that), never had that with my Moto nor with my HTC. With the modem/Baseband you might have a point, though I always considered *all* contents of `/system` part of the ROM – hence my "cannot hurt" above.

Comment: @Izzy It's not Samsung but a Chinese device named Micromax A110q (remember Yureka; same company). There is another device thas has this issue named CUBOT GT-99. At least a million of people uses the former.

Comment: Uh-oh, Yu-whatever... OK, I won't ask any further :) You have your point then: Depending on the device // one better checks twice :)

Comment: the link to motorola bootloader unlock site doesn't work