# Unbrick dead unite 2 phone whose driver is improper

Tags: usb, unbricking

I am using Micromax unite 2 and before a month, i sucessfully rooted it using kinguser. But today morning i checked for updates and upgraded to lollipop from kitkat.

But unfortunately, 2.5 gb of my phone storage was missing. I mean cache and other partition cant be 2.5gb. Will it?? So I tried to factory reset my phone.

The problem started while the reset. The phone froze in the logo it self for almost half an hour. So i removed the battery and tried to hard reset it using recovery mode. Even that failed. But this time the phone is not even starting to show the logo. That is it is dead!!

Can any one help me out.

Note:

None of my pc or laptop is detecting my phone clearly while connecting it through usb. It is detecting and once detected it is uninstalled and once again detects and the cycle continues. This all happens no matter how long i connect it to the pc or laptop.

Comment: If it is getting detected by your PC somehow (install, uninstall cycle you mentioned) then you can revive your phone. Your device has mt6577 chipset and [SP Flash Tool](http://androidxda.com/smart-phone-flash-tool) supports it. I can't guide you much since you'll have to learn and do it on your own, but the way is to search on Google "how to flash mt6577 phone" or the terms "bricked mt6577", "bricked unite 2 mt6577", etc. You get the point.E.g. links -> http://bm-smartphone-reviews.blogspot.in/2012/05/mt6575-flashing-tutorial.html , http://www.chinaphonearena.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=60

Comment: My phone [while correcting its IMEI](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/105966/96277) got bricked badly but I recovered it using **SP flash Tool**.  This tool is good, otherwise, you may have to use MTK droid tools.

Comment: Sorry not working. The phone is not even properly connecting to the PC. If i connect it with battery, it connects and disconnects simultaneously until I plug it out from the port. Any more help?????!!!