# SOLVED - Invalid IMEI - lenovo a7000

Tags: rom, imei, lenovo

So, I recently bricked my A7000. Found a rom somewhere online and flashed it with SPTools. Now it boots fine but I get the "INVALID IMEI" error.

I rooted it gain, got into engineer mode with [MTK Engineering Mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.themonsterit.EngineerStarter&hl=el/apps/details?id=com.cryptotel.chamelephon&hl=el) and run the command `AT +EGMR=1,7,"blabla"` but it's still not working. I get `AT command is sent: ERROR`

Please help...

Comment: I had this issue once. Perhaps, my answer may help: [How to fix "Invalid IMEI " after Factory reset?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/105966)

Comment: @Firelord You mean method #2? Method 1# is exactly what i did to get here..

Comment: Consider following  both the methods and tell us the results.

Comment: @Firelord The first one did nothing. For the second, Maui can't detect the phone, it says "[36] BootROM start command passed, but target has no response untill timeout.." the phone displays some chinese characters and says it is in meta mode (with verry bad grammar).

Comment: Did you try using mtk droid tool ?

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf Not really, I have no idea how to use it. updated^

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.
I rooted with SPTools and used [Chamelephon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cryptotel.chamelephon&hl=el) to enter the IMEI's (if you have dual sim, enter both at the same time!).